# Why is the weight lattice a lattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, integer-lattices, semisimple-lie-algebras

For $\mathfrak g$ a complex semisimple Lie algebra, $\mathfrak h \subset \mathfrak g$ a CSA and $R$ the corresponding set of roots we call the following set $\Lambda_w=\{\lambda \in \mathfrak h^*|\langle\lambda, \alpha^\vee\rangle\in \mathbb Z \text{ for all } \alpha\in R\}$ the **weight lattice**. Why is that set a lattice? It surely is an additive subgroup of $\mathfrak h^*$ and it spans $\mathfrak h^*$ over $\mathbb C$ (since roots are contained in the weight lattice). However, why is it isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$ for $n$ the dimension of $\mathfrak h$? Why do the fundamental dominant weights form a $\mathbb Z$-basis of the weight lattice?

Comment: Have you seen an argument for the fact that if $\langle\lambda,\alpha^{\vee}\rangle=0$ for all $\alpha\in R$, then $\lambda=0$?

Comment: If so, and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are the simple roots, and $n_i=\langle\lambda,\alpha_i^\vee\rangle$, what can you say about $\lambda-\sum_in_i\lambda_i$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Regarding your first question: No, I haven't, but this follows from the fact that the coroots span $\mathfrak h$, right? (One can prove this by looking at the orthogonal complement of the span of the coroots w.r.t. the Killing form). With regards to your second question (I assume you denote by $\lambda_i$ the fundamental dominant weights): One shows that $<\lambda-\sum_i n_i\lambda_i,\alpha_j \check{}>=0$ for all $j=1,...,n$ by using the defining property of the fundamental dominant weights. By your first claim this implies $\lambda=\sum_i n_i \lambda_i$ …

Comment: …Therefore, $\Lambda_w \subset \{ \sum_i n_i \lambda_i | n_i \in \mathbb Z\}$. The other inclusion is straight-forward to see. Hence, $\Lambda_w$ is a lattice with fundamental dominant weights as a $\mathbb Z$-basis, correct?

Comment: Correct. Well done.

Comment: Maybe write up and accept your own answer to remove this from the unanswered questions.